# VBA Application.OnTime goes haywire near 12am

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA program which copies and paste cells from one workbook to another workbook every 5 minutes running 22 hours each day including over midnight using the Application.OnTime loop.

Every day, at 11:55pm my Excel goes haywire and frantically copies and pastes every second. 11:55pm would make my next scheduled update to be 12am which can cause this to happen. Does someone have any workarounds to this problem?

The lines that causes problem is:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K5") = TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Minute(Time), 5) + 5, 0)

Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K5"), Procedure:="dataextract", Schedule:=True
```

So basically I only have a time component to Application.OnTime, but not a date component. Could this be why?

Thank you.

Comment: It works correctly the rest of the day and fails *only* at 11:55pm?

Comment: Yeah that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the date to the earliest time by replacing this line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") _
    .Range("K5") = TimeSerial(Hour(Now), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Minute(Time), 5) + 5, 0)
```

With this line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") _
    .Range("K5") = Now + TimeSerial(0, _
    WorksheetFunction.Floor(Minute(Now), 5) + 5 - Minute(Now), _
    1 - Second(Now))
```

Comment: Cool let me see if this works.. let you know after midnight :P